# Valgrind says i'm not freeing the memory, why is that?

Tags: c, data-structures, valgrind

I have a function that allocates memory for a pair in a linked list and when I run, valgrind says I'm not freeing the memory. Here is my function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
int id;
char type;
}Pair;

typedef struct cel{
void *info;
struct cel *urm;
}Celula, *TLista, **ALista;


TLista assignPair(Pair p){

TLista new_entry = malloc(sizeof(Celula));
if (!new_entry){
    return NULL;
}

new_entry->info = malloc(sizeof(Pair));
if (!new_entry->info){
    free(new_entry);
    return NULL;
}

new_entry->urm = NULL;

((Pair*)new_entry->info)->id = p.id;
((Pair*)new_entry->info)->type = p.type;

return new_entry;

}

int main(){
Pair p;
p.id = 2;
p.type = 'c';
TLista a;
a = assignPair(p);
}
```

When I use in my main, assignPair(p), it says the following:

```
==4068== 24 (16 direct, 8 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==4068==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4068==    by 0x40057B: assignPair (in /home/vaduva/SD/2017/Tema2/example)
==4068==    by 0x40060B: main (in /home/vaduva/SD/2017/Tema2/example)
```

Can anyone please tell me where I'm making a mistake? I read through the manual of valgrind here: [Link to valgrind man page](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)

But that still doesn't help me.

Comment: you are probably forgetting to free them somewhere else, go over the places where Pairs should be freed and check them.

Comment: ha sorry yes :)

Comment: @Olaf I have added a verifiable example of what I'm doing.

Comment: compile with -g and valgrind will give you line numbers in its messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main function, you allocate memory:

```
{
    a = assignPair(p);
} // leaked
```

At the end of the function, `a` goes out of scope, and it was the last pointer referring to that memory.  You need to provide a `freePair()` function in order to release the memory while it's still reachable through `a`:

```
{
    a = assignPair(p);
    /* perhaps some other operations here */
    freePair(a);
}
```

The implementation of `freePair()` should be very straightforward.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind check for `memory leaks`. So when you allocate your memory for a structure or function you should `free the memory` when it is no longer needed. In your program you had allocated using `malloc` twice and has not freed the memory allocated.

So you should free the memory created some where in the code.

```
free(new_entry->info);
free(new_entry);
```

i.e in your code exactly

```
int main() {
Pair p;
p.id = 2;
p.type = 'c';
TLista a;
a = assignPair(p);
free(a->info);
free(a);
}
```

Remember the order in which you free the memory is also factor as you will get a segmentation fault for illegal memory access.

Comment: I can't free the new_entry as I need it to return it.

Comment: There you have to think of ownership. The method transfers the ownership of the struct to its caller. So the caller has to take care of the proper deletion.

Comment: Yes , you cannot free the new_entry but you could free it in function main ,both the pointer a->info and a, probably at the end where your program no longer needs the memory